# float or position:absolute; i dont get it

Tags: css

I'm  a complete  noob  when it come to CSS and HTML, 
I'm trying to get  2 images one to float left and the other right 
so i can place some text  below them .

the  issue I'm having  is  the  float  command and  the position command both stuff  up the page structure and  i don't know  why

Ive  tried  one float  and one position:absolute; but  still  they both stuff  the page. 
as  their is nothing on the HTML page apart from the images and H1 and H2 
the header and footer are both on top  of the page .

any help will be appreciated

thanks 
John

p.s i'm still learning

[what I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL91y.png)

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn4mt.png)

Comment: I would avoid using float to get elements in the same line - give boththe images a css rule of `display: inline-block`

Comment: Are you using any kind of grid?

Answer (score 0):

**position:** *property* - use this in very difficult situations and also for positioning misc. elements like icons/flags and other elements that should always sticks in one position.

**float:** *property* - use when i need to inline elements and i know that they should stick in one side of page or parent container.

**display:** inline-block - this i use for displaying elements inline as inline-blocks, for example `<p></p>` is an inline-block.
but this have "side effect" there will be always white space **between** inline blocks.

if you want to center floated elements:

```
        <style>
          .container {
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
          }

          .centered-box {
            display: inline-block;
            max-width: 100%;
          }

          .elm {
            float: left;
            width: 300px; 
            max-width: 50%;
          }
        </style>


        <div class="container">
          <div class="centered-box">
            <div class="elm">
            </div>

            <div class="elm">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Also, floated elements doesn't act as blocks. They are forced to float up to side you declared till parent container wall or other floated element.
if You want to give space for floated elements use this:

```
.clearfix::before {
    content: "";
    display: table-cell;
}

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

<div class="clearfix">
// flaoted elements
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a framework.

```css
header,
footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.leftcolumn,
.rightcolumn {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftcolumn">
    <h1>header 1</h1>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="rightcolumn">
    <h1>header 1</h1>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```